# post json data to api from angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I've a POST Method route 'http://localhost:5000/cities' which accepts the json data like

```
[{ "id:" 1, "name": "LA", "country": "USA", "value": 10000 }]
```

In angular, the service (cities.service.ts) that posts data

```
export class CitiesService {

constructor() { }

send_cities(data): Observable<Result> {
return this.post(this.Url(), data);
      }
}
```

I've a component (cities.component.ts) that uses this service

```
let city_code = this.form.value;
swal({
    title: '',
    text: '',
    type: 'info',
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true
  }, function () {
    self.citiesService.send_cities(city_code, self._city.id, self._city.name, self._city.country, self._city.value).subscribe(
      response => {
        swal({
          title: "",
          text: "",
          type: "success",
          timer: 1500,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
```

How do I post the data to the api in json format as shown in the example?

Comment: JSON.STRINGIFY() is used to stringify json

Comment: `JSON.stringify(yourVariable)` - casing is important

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Ok, Ive edited it. Can you help with how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your method need to send an array with your information that you want to send, this is my little change to achive it:

```js
swal({
    title: '',
    text: '',
    type: 'info',
    showCancelButton: true,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true
  }, function () {
    self.citiesService.send_cities([{self._city.id, self._city.name, self._city.country, self._city.value}]).subscribe(
      response => {
        swal({
          title: "",
          text: "",
          type: "success",
          timer: 1500,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Gabriel, but I want to post the data as key-value pairs as mentioned in the example. How can I do that?

Comment: So you need to change your code like it: JSON.stringify([{self._city.id, self._city.name, self._city.country, self._city.value}]). It'll tranform this object an string: "[{ "id:" 1, "name": "LA", "country": "USA", "value": 10000 }]"

Comment: Remembering that Angular transforms automatically object to key-value pairs in request

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm sorry I forget to add a line in my snippet. I think now Json stringfy won't work as I'm just passing a integer `city_code`

Comment: Change to this: JSON.stringify([{id: city_code, self._city.name, self._city.country, self._city.value}])

Comment: I'm not understanding well what you want, because if you don't want to send city_code, just remove it, if you want to change the name or something else, just rename the field: {test1: teste2}.